# How to build mutiple web deployment packages in a VS2012 solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, msbuild, webdeploy

I can find plenty of examples of building a single web deployment package from a project file but I want to use the same technique in an automated build environment. When I try to specify the parameter as an msbuild argument I end up with packages created in the /obj directory. I want to specify the output location as a folder into which all project files in solution will be created but this isn't working for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked this out based on a post from Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi I adpated the approach as outlined below

```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <DeployOnBuild Condition=" '$(BuildPackages)'!='' ">$(BuildPackages)</DeployOnBuild>
  <DesktopBuildPackageLocation Condition=" '$(BuildPackages)'!='' ">$(DeployPackageLocation)\$(AssemblyName)\$(AssemblyName).zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Basically adding the BuildPackages and DeployPackageLocation mean that a root location for deployment packages can be controlled by a solution/global parameter and a build level switch like below

```
> MSBUILD <SolutionPath>.sln /P:Configuration=Release /P:Platform="Any CPU" /P:BuildPackages=true /P:DeployPackageLocation="<YourOutputLocation>"
```

There are more details on my blog

Comment: Could you please add links to Sayed's and your blog post